# The meaning of "contribute unique variance"

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-meaning

What is the usage and meaning of "contribute unique variance" in this sentence?

> For children with typical language, orthographic knowledge and morphological knowledge **contributed unique variance** to spelling performance.

<sup>Source: Werfel, K.L., & Schuele, C.M. (2012, November).

[Contribution of linguistic knowledge to spelling performance in elementary school children with and without language impairment.](http://sph.sc.edu/wll/pdf/Werfel_dissertation_ASHA2012.pdf) Poster presented at the Annual Convention of the American Speech-Language-Hearing Association, Atlanta, GA.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

We are talking about statistics here.

[Variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance) gives the way / to which degree the meassured data (in this case: spelling performance) is distributed.

[Contribute](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/contribute) here means play a part in, influence something.

So in plain English (non-mathematician translation w/o having read the paper),

> Orthographic knowledge and morphological knowledge both influence the meassurable variance of the spelling performance in a characteristic way.

Comment: Thank you, what is the role of unique? does it main the certain? or same for both of knowledge?

Comment: It's "unique variance", but I can only guess at what it means exactly - I would assume each type of knowledge having a different influence.

Comment: I didn't study it completely, but I think two knowledge (orthography and morphological) are in the same category and have the same effect. I am even suspicious that he means "Orthographic and morphological knowledge contribute unique variance to spelling performance."